# Tagged Topics Are Off Topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

The list of tags for Super User includes...

- Android
- Date-Time

So I posted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/563791/android-time-and-date-are-wrong)

To my surprise, the question was down-voted, my reputation has been hit, and the question was closed as off-topic.

I really am confused.

If Super User contains tags for both Android and Date-Time, then why is a question about setting the date-time on an Android closed as off topic ?

Is there an appropriate StackExchange Community for questions about Androids ?

Should I delete my question to protect my reputation ? Or has the damage been permanently done ?

Comment: Have you read the tag's description, which clearly says, *"Unless the device docks with your computer, questions are better on android.stackexchange.com (…)"*? Also, browsing the [latest questions tagged `android`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/android) reveals quite a few ones closed or migrated.

Comment: [android.se] of course, but please do read the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: The FAQ ought to be changed so that Android is included as _**on-topic**_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, the existence of a tag does not indicate being on-topic. Anybody with [300 reputation points can create a tag](https://superuser.com/privileges/create-tags), and there's no specific review process for that. In fact, if you look around here on Meta you'll see a lot of recent requests to remove or blacklist useless or off-topic tags.

Specifically regarding Android, there are some questions relating to Android that could be on topic. Refer to the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) to see specifically what is on topic for this site:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - programming and software development,
> - video games or consoles,
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
> - **electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, *except insofar as they interface with your computer*,**
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
> - asking for a shopping or product recommendation,
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

A question about how Android interfaces with a computer would be allowed; thus the tag is a valid one to have around. Questions more specifically about Android should be asked on the Stack Exchange site for [Android Answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Deleting your own question will restore the reputation points lost. Beware though that if you ask a lot of questions that get downvoted, closed, and/or deleted, you may be automatically banned from asking any more questions in the future. As such, you should be careful about deleting questions, and instead work to ensure that your questions are on-topic before asking them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try to do better. Thanks a lot.